# Android Studio AlertDialog - show multiple messages

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to make an alert dialog that would allow the user to enter the name of a new point of interest with its longitude and latitude. Overall, it should look like this:

> Add a new point of interest
>
> Enter the position of the new point of
>   interest
>
> Enter name:
>
> [editText]
>
> Enter longitude:
>
> [editText]
>
> Enter latitude:
>
> [editText]

This is my code so far:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_add_task:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Add a new point of interest");
                builder.setMessage("Enter the position of the new point of interest");
                final EditText inputField1 = new EditText(this);
                builder.setView(inputField1);


                builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        String poi = inputField1.getText().toString();

                        helper = new TaskDBHelper(MainActivity.this);
                        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                        values.clear();
                        values.put(TaskContract.Columns.POI,poi);

                        db.insertWithOnConflict(TaskContract.POI_NAMES,null,values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
                        updateUI();
                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",null);

                builder.create().show();
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
```

How can I modify it to add multiple inputs field and set multiple messages?
For example if I do something like this:

```
builder.setMessage("Enter the position of the new point of interest");
builder.setMessage("Enter name:");
```

it will only show

> Enter name:

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom layout as per your requirement and bind that layout to the `AlertDialog` in this manner

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(dialoglayout);
builder.show();
```